# Codeigniter Tank Auth not sending activation Email

Tags: codeigniter, email, tankauth

I am using Tank Auth with codeigniter for Email verification of user on registration. After registering it is showing "Registered successfully. Check your activation email." But I am not recieving any activation Email.

Settings I am using in Application/config/email.php are as follows:

```
 $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
 $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com";
 $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
 $config['smtp_user'] = "My Gmail";//also valid  Google Apps Accounts
 $config['smtp_pass'] = "My Password";
 $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
 $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
 $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

This default mail function used by TankAuth in Controller:

```
function _send_email($type, $email, &$data)
    {
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->from($this->config->item('webmaster_email', 'tank_auth'), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth'));
        $this->email->reply_to($this->config->item('webmaster_email', 'tank_auth'), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth'));
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject(sprintf($this->lang->line('auth_subject_'.$type), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth')));
        $this->email->message($this->load->view('email/'.$type.'-html', $data, TRUE));
        $this->email->set_alt_message($this->load->view('email/'.$type.'-txt', $data, TRUE));
        $this->email->send();
    }
```

Do I need to do anything else? As I am not recieving any activation emails using these settings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably don't need the ssl:// in the smtp_host variable as it is a protocol not part of a hostname.

Comment: @Joe Changed it. Still getting message "A new activation email has been sent to yourid@gmail.com. Follow the instructions in the email to activate your account." But no email in INbox.

Comment: I don't use google apps for email, do you have to set anything on there to allow you to send email using their SMTP server? It seems like your app believes the message is being sent. I would also write a quick method to test that you can send emails using those credentials and have it dump the result to screen.

Comment: I have edited question and added the default mailing function of TankAuth

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the debugging method for the email library? http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/email.html#CI_Email.print_debugger

Comment: I tried $this->email->print_debugger(array('headers')); but it gave blank output

Comment: Did you set $this->email->send(FALSE) first as it says in the instructions?

Comment: Yes. Setting FALSE giving blank output too.

Comment: I'm not convinced the email is ever being sent then, that should at least contain the sent message even if the server returns no errors.

Comment: SMTP email settings are not being recognised for some reasons maybe. It is default code that comes with TankAuth , as other user are using the same code the possible error could be only in email settings that we need to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below settings:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';

$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';

$config['smtp_user'] = 'My Gmail';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'My Password';
```

And in send mail function, add set the new line code before 'from'

```
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from($this->config->item('webmaster_email', 'tank_auth'), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am getting Same Results